# Base image column doesn't exist in admin panel on product page

Tags: image, magento

By default in Magento for product images exist column "Base image". But it doesn't exist in my project, probably someone deleted it or something like that.

[image]

How to return it?

Should be

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is `image` system attribute and user can not delete this from admin panel. Please check in your current attribute set from Attributes >> Manage Attribute Sets. It may be possible by mistake someone drag this in another group.

[image]

[image]

You need to drag `image` attribute in Images attribute group to resole the issue.

Comment: I have the same configuration http://i.imgur.com/r26MWqP.png

http://i.imgur.com/r9s24yR.png